# Does MongoDB MapReduce lock the database

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Does a MongoDB MapReduce job lock the database?  I am developing a multi-user MongoDB web application and am worried about multi-user conflicts and performance.  Does anyone have any words of wisdom for me?

Comment: Words of wisdom wise, note my comment on the accepted answer WRT parallelism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer? Sometimes ...

It depends a lot on how you are using map/reduce ... but in my experience it's never been a problem.

There isn't much info on this, but it's clearly stated in the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work#Howdoesconcurrencywork-Read/WriteLock) that is does *sometimes* lock but it ***"Allows substantial concurrent operation."***

There are a couple of questions in the mongodb-user group [asking](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/search?group=mongodb-user&q=map%20reduce%20lock&qt_g=Search%20this%20group) about this ... the best response I've seen [offically](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/452c0b48ce7fd280/414655d1893feaf2?lnk=gst&q=mapreduce%20lock#414655d1893feaf2) is that ... "in 1.4 it yields but isn't as nice as it should be, in 1.5 its much friendlier to other requests."

That does not mean that it *doesn't block at all*, but compared to db.eval() which blocks the [whole mongod process](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Writelocks) ... it's your best bet.

That said, in 1.7.2 and up there is now a ***nolock*** option for db.eval() ...

Comment: Keep in mind however that the most important issue is being glossed over: MapReduce locks the entire Javscript Context, of which there is only one per mongod.  Hence, you cannot run multiple simultaneous MapReduce jobs on a single MongoDB server; be careful using it as a query mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

No, mapreduce does not lock the database. See [the note here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution), just after "Using db.eval()" (it explains why mapreduce may be more appropriate to use than eval, because mapreduce does not block).

If you are going to run a lot of mapreduce jobs you should use sharding, because that way the job can run in parallel on all the shards. Unfortunately mapreduce jobs can't run on secondaries in a replica set, since the results must be written and replicas are read-only.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.1.0 added a "nonAtomic" flag to output option.

See: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2581