# MongoDB - How does locking work for Map Reduce?

Tags: mongodb, cron, mapreduce

Does MongoDB map reduce lock a collection when performing an operation on it?

I have some collections that are widely and intensively used by an application.  A Map/Reduce runs in the background every 10 minutes via a cron job, on that widely and intensively used collection.

I want to know if there is a high probability that Map/Reduce won't perform well because other operations are in progress (inserts, updates, and mostly reads) on that collection. In particular, I want know if Map/Reduce interferes with normal operations performed on the collection by users.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563172/does-mongodb-mapreduce-lock-the-database

Comment: ok thanks, so it is a little presumable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce, if outputting to a collection will take multiple write locks out as it writes (as any operation which is creating/updating a collection would).  If you are doing an in-line MR, then you avoid that locking (but have limitations on result sizes).  Even so, there are still read-locks and the Javascript lock (single threaded for server side JS on mongoDB right now).

This is all explained (and will be updated if it changes) here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work#Howdoesconcurrencywork-MapReduce

Note: the SpiderMonkey to V8 JS engine migration issues are ones to watch if multi-threading is something you are concerned about.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when mapreduce finish work and it is in progress to output on "temp_result_collection", in that instant mongodb lock and simultaneous the request of other operations are in queue since mapreduce output finish? but if output take some seconds (example 10 sec because it is big output) it is not a problem. But when mapreduce read data from collection for processing it ( run emit and reduce funcion ) it  preserve lock on initial collection? I ask this because I'm implementing a voting system in mongodb, and I store votes as nested doc of each objects in diff collection

Comment: "It reads from a collection (read lock yielded every 100 documents)" So, if a user consult simultaneous one of that records that are locked  user wait until it is released on that 100 documents?, so read operation perform by user it is put in queue, so it isn't return a error, right?

Comment: First, to take advantage of yielding fully, make sure you are on the 2.x version (currently 2.0.4) where yielding has been improved.  The 100 documents is not a unit of locking, instead the MR job take out a read lock (multiple read locks are allowed) and yields it every 100 documents.  Why? because write locks are exclusive, so if a write is waiting, the yield will allow that write to happen.  Take a look at Dwight's presentations on 10gen.com for a more detailed and informative explanation on how all this works.